# Opencart 3.x new theme in not showing in admin panel?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am not new to OpenCart, but I never try OpenCart after `version 1.5.6`. I can see there are a lot of changes during this time. When I wanted to add a new theme, I copied my theme into the directory `catalog\view\theme`, but there is no link to select the theme into `System >> Settings >> Edit >> Theme`. Even it is not listed in `Design >> Theme Editor >> Choose your store`.

Although I am going to dig into deeper about this new release, during this time any help will be appreciable. *And importantly there are few google searches which all are not about the specified version.*

**N.B. I know OpenCart added `.twig` template in this release and my new theme is compatible with OpenCart v-3.0.2.0**

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down voting, that will help me to understand why.

Comment: are you use any Premium theme?

Comment: Hello @HarnishDesign, no it's not a premium theme but a custom theme developed by myself. I finally have found according to `kinkliam` answer. I will edit his answer or will post a new answer about my fix.

Answer (score 2):

Try logging into your admin portal and then

1. Navigate to Extensions >> Extensions
2. Click the edit icon on your default store theme
3. Edit the "Theme Directory" from "default" to one of your new folders

Comment: OpenCart made a lot of changes from 1.x to 2.x and then 2.x to 3.x. By the way, it is not about to edit theme. Actually I did not find where to activate the theme. You save me a lot of time.

Comment: Yes that works, but it does not show up under the theme editor, only default shows.  How do you get the new theme to show up in the theme editor?